# AWS Lambda Selenium WebDriver - Error Loading ibglib-2.0.so

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda

I'm trying to run a headless version of Chrome in a Lamdba function.  I need a way to request a url, load the page and run any javascript on that page.  So far my funcion is:

```
public class Function
{
    public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = GetDriver(context);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.mybaggage.com/");
        driver.Quit();

        return input?.ToUpper();
    }

    public IWebDriver GetDriver(ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var tmpPath = Path.GetTempPath();

        DriverManager driveManager = new DriverManager();
        driveManager.SetUpDriver(
            "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/85.0.4183.38/chromedriver_linux64.zip",
            Path.Combine(tmpPath, "chromedriver"),
            "chromedriver"
        );

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        
        options.AddArguments(new List<string>() {
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--headless",
            "--disable-gpu",
            $"--homedir={tmpPath}"
        });

        return new ChromeDriver(tmpPath, options);
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

`/tmp/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I've added a package called glib, however I still recieve the error.  The packages installed are:

```
<PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="glib" Version="2.36.2.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
<PackageReference Include="WebDriverManager" Version="2.9.3" />
```

Is there a way to resolve the error?